# How to assign minimal privileges for create view

Tags: permissions, db2, view, db2-luw

In Db2 v11.1 on Linux we have a request to create a new user with access only to the "create view" privilege.

What are minimal permissions I have to set in order for the user to be able create views and of course check if the view is working fine?

Comment: Documentation shows privileges required for each SQL statement; have you checked that out?

Answer (score 1):

1. On Database level CONNECT privilege is required:

   `db2 grant CONNECT on database to user user1`

   Note: This may not be required if the `PUBLIC` group has connect privilege (which is the default setting).
2. Every table that is referenced in the view has to have the `SELECT` privilege

   `db2 grant select on table schema1.table1 to user user1`
3. To create a view user has to have a privilege to create/alter/drop objects in the schema

   `db2 grant createin, alterin, dropin on schema schema1 to user user1`
4. Instead of step 3 the ownership of schema can be transferred to the new user (if desired)

   `db2 transfer ownership of schema schema1 to user user1`